# Grouping a list of main objects by their nested object's id

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Given the following class `A` :

```
public class A {
    private int id; //this field is unique
    private int a_1; //this field ain't unique
    private String a_2;
    private String a_3;
    
    //setters + getters
}
```

We can group a `list` of random objects of type `A` as follow by their respective `a_1` :

```
Map<String, List<A>> sortedmap = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getA_1, Collectors.toList()));
```

Now given two classes `B` and `C` such as :

```
public class B{
    private int id; //this field is unique for all entities of type B
    private String b_1;
    private C b_C; //many objects of type B may have a reference to the same object of type C
    
    //setters + getters
}

public class C{
    private int id; //this field is unique for all entities of type C
    private String c_1;
    private D c_D; //many objects of type C may have a reference to the same object of type D
    
    //setters + getters
}

public class D{
    private int id; //this field is unique for all entities of type D
    private String d_1;
    private String d_2;
    
    //setters + getters
}
```

How can we sort a list of random objects of type `B` by their respective `b_C.getC_D().getId()` field?

Comment: you can use `Comparator`

Comment: Do you mean 'sort' (which doesn't match the question's title) or 'group'? If group, the answer is really just the same but you can't use a method reference: `Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b.getB_C().getC_D().getId(), Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @sprinter yes sort, I edited the thread.

Comment: @saka1029 what's the return type? I need a map of type Map<String, List<B>> where the key is the b.getB_C().getC_D().getId()

Comment: Did you mean group by `b_C.getC_D().getId()` and sort list of group by `b_C.getC_D().getId()`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the results in a TreeMap which is ordered by default:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    D d1 = new D();d1.setId(1);
    D d2 = new D();d2.setId(2);
    
    C c1 = new C();c1.setC_D(d1);
    C c2 = new C(); c2.setC_D(d2);
    
    B b1 = new B(); b1.setB_C(c1); b1.setId(1);
    B b2 = new B(); b2.setB_C(c2); b2.setId(2);
    B b3 = new B(); b3.setB_C(c2); b3.setId(3);
    
    Map<String, List<B>> result = Arrays.asList(b1,b2,b3)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> ""+b.getB_C().getC_D().getId(),
                     TreeMap::new, 
                     Collectors.toList()));
        
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The result is:

```
{1=[B [id=1]], 2=[B [id=2], B [id=3]]}
```

PS. @javaistaucheineinsel nice username ;)

Answer (score 0):

I’d add custom getters to support this (not compiled, forgive typos):

```
public class B{
    private int id; //this field is unique for all entities of type B
    private String b_1;
    private C b_C; //many objects of type B may have a reference to the same object of type C
    
    //setters + getters

    public int getBCDId() {
        return b_C.getCDId();
    }
}

public class C{
    private int id; //this field is unique for all entities of type C
    private String c_1;
    private D c_D; //many objects of type C may have a reference to the same object of type D
    
    //setters + getters

    public int getCDId() {
        return c_D.getId();
    }
}
```

Now you can sort and/or group `B` objects by the value they return from their `getBCDId` methods. Just like you would do for `B`’s own attributes.